# How to find multiple words in multiple websites using Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, text-mining

I have a list of 100+ companies and I want to know if they have specific products, certifications. I have used the code below to count the number **1 specific word** in multiple websites (found the code from kind-hearted strangers in stackoverflow). (A) But, how can I edit the query the_word to include multiple words?

(B) Also, what about partial words,such as I want a line with the word "certification" but, it can be also there as '...we certified...' or, '...received certificate...'. I guess the easy hack is to use all possible words and search them. In SQL, there are wildcard letters, such as LIKE certi% . Is there any similar ideas?

THANKS IN ADVANCE !!!

````
#Counts and gives the lines in websites
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_list = ["http://www.a-w-s.co.uk/","http://www.albanywindows.co.uk","http://www.aimwindows.co.uk"]

#the_word = input()
the_word = 'UKCA','CA

total_words = []
for url in url_list:
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content.lower(), 'lxml')
    words = soup.find_all(text=lambda text: text and the_word.lower() in text)
    count = len(words)
    words_list = [ ele.strip() for ele in words ]
    for word in words:
        total_words.append(word.strip())

    print('\nUrl: {}\ncontains {} of word: {}'.format(url, count, the_word))
    print(words_list)

#print(total_words)
total_count = len(total_words) ```


Works for 1 word but, when I tried,  
the_word= 'UKCA', 'CA', 'PS24' 
the_word= ['UKCA', 'CA', 'PS24']
the_word= ('UKCA', 'CA', 'PS24') 

Error... How to fix this!
````

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using list comprehension (for multiple input) and [regex](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp) (for pattern/partial matching). Also, since you just want the text, you can use [`.stripped_strings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) directly instead `.find_all(text...)` followed by `.strip`.

```py
# import re # for regex

## ENSURE the_word IS A LIST OF [lowercase] STRINGS ##
if type(the_word) in [list, tuple, set]:
    the_word = [str(w).lower() for w in the_word]
else: the_word = [str(the_word).lower()]
######################################################

total_words = []
for url in url_list:
    r = requests.get(url) # , allow_redirects=False) # why block redirects?
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content.lower(), 'lxml')
    # words_list = [s for s in soup.stripped_strings if [w for w in the_word if re.search(w, s)]]
    words_list = [
        s.strip() for s in soup.find_all(text=True) 
        if s.parent.name not in ['script', 'style']
        and [w for w in the_word if re.search(w, s)]
    ]
    count = len(words_list)
    total_words += words_list

    print('\nUrl: {}\ncontains {} matches for {}'.format(
        url, count, ' or '.join([f'"{w}"' for w in the_word])
    ), '\n', words_list, '\n')

total_count = len(total_words)
print(f'\n{total_count} found for {the_word}\n', total_words)
```

(I removed `allow_redirects=False` from the requests because the second and third sites give [301 error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/301) otherwise.)

---

Now, `the_word` can have multiple strings/patterns to search for; for example, setting

```py
the_word = ['composite',  'condensation', 'surface']
# same results as with:  
# the_word = ('composite',  'condensation', 'surface')
# the_word = {'composite',  'condensation', 'surface'}
```

would lead to printing

```py
Url: http://www.a-w-s.co.uk/
contains 1 matches for "composite" or "condensation" or "surface" 
 ['surface guarantee'] 


Url: http://www.albanywindows.co.uk
contains 6 matches for "composite" or "condensation" or "surface" 
 ['composite doors', 'composite door builder', 'composite doors', 'composite door builder', ', including improved thermal efficiency and minimised risk of interior condensation. we also offer', 'composite door'] 


Url: http://www.aimwindows.co.uk
contains 5 matches for "composite" or "condensation" or "surface" 
 ['composite doors', 'composite fire doors', 'composite doors', 'composite fire doors', 'for a closer look at the finer, technical specifics of our renovation products, our detailed brochures are readily available to download. from versatile casement windows to captivating aluminium bifold doors & ultra-secure composite doors, embrace the opportunity to pursue your home improvement aspirations with aim windows.'] 


12 found for ['composite', 'condensation', 'surface']
 ['surface guarantee', 'composite doors', 'composite door builder', 'composite doors', 'composite door builder', ', including improved thermal efficiency and minimised risk of interior condensation. we also offer', 'composite door', 'composite doors', 'composite fire doors', 'composite doors', 'composite fire doors', 'for a closer look at the finer, technical specifics of our renovation products, our detailed brochures are readily available to download. from versatile casement windows to captivating aluminium bifold doors & ultra-secure composite doors, embrace the opportunity to pursue your home improvement aspirations with aim windows.']
```

---

With regex, the "wildcard" character is `.` [or `.*` (zero or more chars) or `.?` (zero or one) or `.+` (one or more)], and you can also specify possible character in square brackets; so setting `the_word = 'mo.e[y!n]'` would find matches in strings containing "***mo**r**e**!*" or "***mo**m**e**n*t" or "***mo**n**e**y*"

```py
Url: http://www.a-w-s.co.uk/
contains 1 matches for "mo.e[y!n]" 
 ['we are the uk’s leading manufacturers and suppliers to the trade, with a huge range of pvcu and aluminium windows, doors, bifolds, sliding patios, heritage flush sash products, conservatories, and more!'] 


Url: http://www.albanywindows.co.uk
contains 1 matches for "mo.e[y!n]" 
 ["both being a+ rated, you can be sure that heat won't escape your home and you'll be protected against draughts. this helps you save money in the long run as you'll be spending less on your heating bills."] 


Url: http://www.aimwindows.co.uk
contains 1 matches for "mo.e[y!n]" 
 ['our showroom is temporarily closed at the moment.'] 


3 found for ['mo.e[y!n]']
 ['we are the uk’s leading manufacturers and suppliers to the trade, with a huge range of pvcu and aluminium windows, doors, bifolds, sliding patios, heritage flush sash products, conservatories, and more!', "both being a+ rated, you can be sure that heat won't escape your home and you'll be protected against draughts. this helps you save money in the long run as you'll be spending less on your heating bills.", 'our showroom is temporarily closed at the moment.']
```

Comment: Wow !! Many many thanks for the comprehensive suggestion and codes ! But, when I tested it for a random door-window website, 

https://tpimprovements.com/
There was error message
'''
'contains 36 matches for "door" or "window" 
 ['var gform;gform||(document.addeventlistener("gform_main_scripts_loaded",function(){gform.scriptsloaded=!0}),window.addeventlistener("domcontentloaded",function()................................................... '''

Why is it not showing in normal lines like before?

Comment: @nihility24 [I don't think it's an error message?] that's from the `script` tag. I think maybe we have different parser versions because that result doesn't show up for me (but I can see the tag with `soup.select('script')`); I've edited my code to use `find_all(text=True)` (like you were, but more simply) instead of `stripped_strings` because then you can filter by parent tag properties as well